# Update programmatically custom attribute value set in a WooCommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

If I already have existing product attributes and then use the function below, it removes existing attributes from the product and replaces them with this one attribute.

I only want to update this one attribute value with a new value programmatically.

Do I have to read the existing attributes array with get_post_meta first and update it? I am just trying to find out if there is an alternative method.

```
function update_internalSKU() {
  $product_id = 850;
  $product_attributes = array();
  $product_attributes['internalSKU'] = array(
      'name' => 'internalSKU',
      'value' => 'b8de7569042',
      'position' => 1,
      'is_visible' => 0,
      'is_variation' => 0,
      'is_taxonomy' => 0
  );
  update_post_meta( $product_id ,'_product_attributes', $product_attributes);
}
update_internalSKU();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `"internalSKU"` seems to be a **custom product attribute**. So yes you need first to get the array of product attributes *(as your product can have other product attributes set for it)*, to update only the required `value` as follows:

```
// Define the function
function update_internalSKU( $product_id ) {
    // Get product attributes
    $product_attributes = get_post_meta( $product_id ,'_product_attributes', true);

    // Loop through product attributes
    foreach( $product_attributes as $attribute => $attribute_data ) {
        // Target specif attribute  by its name
        if( 'internalSKU' === $attribute_data['name'] ) {
            // Set the new value in the array
            $product_attributes[$attribute]['value'] ='b8de7569042'; 
            break; // stop the loop
        }
    }
    // Set updated attributes back in database
    update_post_meta( $product_id ,'_product_attributes', $product_attributes );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

Now you can run this function anywhere defining its `$product_id` argument *(for product id `850`)* like:

```
// Run the function for specific product Id
update_internalSKU( 850 );
```

Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec! Cheers!!