# Transfer value from custom field to attribute in WooCOmmerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to autommaticly transfer a product's custom field **value** to an attribute value.

If a product has the custom field (lagerplacering) and The attribute (lagerplacering): The value from the custom field will override the current attribute value.
If a product has the custom field (lagerplacering) but not the attribute: The attribute will be created and the value added.

I am woking from [Update programmatically custom attribute value set in a WooCommerce product](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65690805)

This is what I have

```
// Define the function
function update_lager( $product_id ) {
    //get the custom field  
    $lagerplacering  = get_post_meta( $product_id ,'_Lagerplacering', true);

if ($lagerplacering) {
    // Get product attributes
    $product_attributes = get_post_meta( $product_id ,'_product_attributes', true);

    // Loop through product attributes
    foreach( $product_attributes as $attribute => $attribute_data ) {
            // Set the new value in the array
            $product_attributes[$attribute]['value'] = $lagerplacering; 
            break; // stop the loop
       }
    }
    // Set updated attributes back in database
    update_post_meta( $product_id ,'_product_attributes', $product_attributes );
}

//run the function when a product is being updated
add_action('save_post_product', 'transfer_value_on_product_save', 10, 1);
function transfer_value_on_product_save( $product_id) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
   update_lager( $product_id );
}
```

It's not working.

Comment: Do you intend to add the **value** to an existing attribute (if so, what is the name?) OR to create a new product attribute? and do you want to keep or overwrite the existing attributes/values?

Comment: the attribute is lagerplacering and yes I want to owerwrite the value.